# Why do I get an error when upgrading from ExtJS 4.2.1 to ExtJS 5?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I executed the following as specified in the ExtJS 5 upgrade guide:

sencha app upgrade -ext

And I got this output with error:

```
sencha app upgrade -ext
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160
[INF] Downloading ext package...
[INF] Source File : http://cdn.sencha.com/cmd/packages/e....0.970/ext.pkg
[INF] Downloading : ....................
[INF] Extracting ext package...
[INF] Package is already local: ext/5.0.0.970
[INF] Extracting : ....................
[INF] Loading configuration for framework directory: C:\Sencha\Cmd\repo\extract\ext\5.0.0.970
[INF] Removing existing framework at C:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\ext
[INF] upgrading application
[INF] Upgrading to sdk at C:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\ext
[INF] Updating application and workspace from Ext JS 4.2.1.883 / Cmd 4.0.2.67
[WRN] Use merge tool to resolve conflict: C:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\usx\.sencha\app\sencha.cfg
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 second
[ERR] org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: Failed creating background process
(C:\Sencha\Cmd\5.0.0.160\ant\ant-util.js#849)
[ERR]
The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (4.0.2.67)
the current is 5.0.0.160.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 5.0.0.160.
```

And when I execute simply "sencha app upgrade" I get this:

```
Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160
[INF] upgrading application
[INF] Upgrading to sdk at C:\atlantis\amc\gui\src\main\ext
[INF] Updating application and workspace from Ext JS 4.2.1.883 / Cmd 3.0.0.250
[ERR] org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (anonymous#336)
[ERR]
The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (0.0.0.0)
the current is 5.0.0.160.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 5.0.0.160.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding app.cmd.version=3.0.0.250 (or whatever version of cmd you *were* running) to your app's sencha.cfg file.  That works for me.

Comment: still work on sencha cmd 6.0.0.202 to latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why, I also got the above error upgrading from Ext 5 Beta to GA and the only way was to generate the app anew (`sencha generate app ...`) and manually copy files to the newly generated folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

on Linux it's the default to have it defined in /root/.bashrc (no clue why it says 3_0_0):

```
export PATH=/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.0.0.160:$PATH
export SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0="/root/bin/Sencha/Cmd/5.0.0.160"
```

on Windows... goto "System Settings" -> "Advanced" -> "Environment Variables..."

and define it there (then one can simply type "sencha" and it will be known).

if the installer doesn't function as it should (Linux example):

```
cd /tmp/sencha1403206728375
./SenchaCmd-5.0.0.160-linux-x64.run
cd .. && rm -R ./sencha1403206728375/
```

I believe the installer prefers to be called from the current directory - this helps at at least when `sencha upgrade` gets stuck.

one needs to reconnect (reboot?) once the environment was updated, in order to extend the PATH spec. with updated SenchCmd one then can use the updated SDK (seems downward compatible).